# Number theory tricky

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
be defined as follows: for every natural number $m$, $f(m)$ is the smallest natural number $k$ such that there exists a sequence $m=a_1<a_2<...<a_t=k$ for which $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \cdots \cdot a_t$ is a square.

Prove: $f$ is injective, and its range is exactly all of the composite numbers.

I've found that for prime numbers $p$ we have $f(p)=2p$, so it's injective on prime numbers. But I have no idea about the rest.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions lacks details and context. Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far? You can find some remarks about how to ask a good question here https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is $f(p)=2p$?  With $p=3$, that would mean that there was a good sequence that ended in $6$, no?  But the only options are $\{3,6\}$, $\{3,5,6\}$ (including the square $4$ can't change anything, right?) and neither of those work.

Comment: @lulu, a bit of experimentation suggests that perhaps $f(p) = 2p$ for $p > 3$ a prime. So $2, 3$ are the exceptions. Edit: specifically, for $p > 3$ a prime, I always find twice a square in the interval $(p, 2p)$, so I can make the sequence $(p, 2n^2, 2p)$ for some $n$. Clearly $f(p) \geq 2p$, so this works.

Comment: I mean for primes greater than 3

Comment: @MeesdeVries  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first show that $f$ is injective.

Suppose to the contrary that $f$ is not. To be precise, suppose that $f(m_1) = f(m_2) = n$ and $m_1 < m_2$. By the hypothesis there are sequences $\{m_1^0 = m_1, \ m_1^1 \cdots, \  m_1^{l_1} = n\}$ and $\{m_2^0 = m_1, \ m_2^1 \cdots, \  m_2^{l_2} = n\}$ such that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\prod_{i=0}^{l_1} m_1^i &= M_1^2;\\
\prod_{i=0}^{l_2} m_2^i &= M_2^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
for some $M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb N$, and no other such sequence starting with $m_1$ 
 or $m_2$ terminates with smaller $n$.

Construct a new sequence by joining the two sequence together, arrange them in increasing order, and kill (both instances of) all duplicated terms. For instance, if the original sequences are $\{2, 8\}$ and $\{3, 6, 8\}$, then the new sequence will be $\{2, 3, 6, \not 8, \not 8\} = \{2,3,6\}$.

It is easy to see that the new sequence starts with $m_1$, terminates with something strictly less than $n$, and its product is a square, hence we arrive at a contradiction.

Now we show that the range of $f$ is exactly the composite numbers. Here I want to point out that since $f(1) = 1$, you need to consider $1$ as composite.

Let $n > 1$ be a composite number. For brevity suppose $n$ is not a square. We need to find a number $m$ such that $f(m) = n$. Since $n$ is composite, we have $n = d_1 d_2$ for some $2 \leq d_1 < d_2$. So we have a sequence $\{d_1, d_2, n\}$ such that $d_1d_2n = n^2$. If $f(d_1) = n$, then we are done. If $f(d_1) = n' < n$, then we have a sequence $\{m_0 = d_1, \ m_1 \cdots, \  m_l = n'\}$ such that

$$
\prod_{i=0}^l m_i = M^2
$$
for some integer $M$.

Do the exclusive or (as in the first part) on the two sequences, and we will get a new sequence. The new sequence starts with something strictly larger than $d_1$, terminates with $n$, and the product of the sequence is a square. Repeat this process, and we will end up with some number $m$ such that $f(m) = n$.

Finally, as Mees de Vries suggested in the comment, we need to show that the primes are not in the range. This is true, since for any sequence $\{m_0, \cdots, m_l = p\}$ which ends at a prime, we know that $p$ divides the product $\prod_{i=0}^l m_i$, but $p^2$ does not, so the product cannot be a square.

Comment: This answer is missing one (maybe too trivial to mention) detail: no prime $p$ is in the image of $f$, because the associated "$M^2$" could never have $p^2 \mid M^2$, even though $p \mid M^2$.

Comment: You are right. As we need to show that the range is "exactly", but not only "containing" the composite numbers, your argument is essential. I will edit the post.